# Convert MySQL db to embeddable database for Java jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, netbeans

Before I created a project which is a huge system, I didn't know that `Mysql` database can't be embedded to a project in Java created in **Netbeans**.

What I did was to add `Mysql Connector J` **jar** file to my project then I used **Mysql Workbench IDE** to manage and create the database and objects such as the stored procedures.

The database is now contained in **Mysql Workbench** which is outside of the Netbeans project.

I have a huge project and 40-50s of stored procedures(used as `CallableStatements` in project), about 20 or more tables.

Eventually when project is complete and ready, I think I will need to embed the database together with the project (which I haven't done in the past).

I don't know how I can possibly solve this because I don't want to rewrite the tables and stored procedures from scratch if I use a different database such as `Derby` and `H2`.

Also, the reason I used the **MySQL Workbench** is to have a GUI for viewing my tables and its properties.

By the way the project is a desktop application done in `Swing`.

What is the best action and solution that you can advise?

I hope you can help.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by *The database is now contained in Mysql Workbench*?

Comment: Mysql Workbench is tool to access the MySQL database and doesn't tables and stuff in itself. They're stored in the actual database.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Actually what I meant was I created the schema in Mysql Workbench in localhost but not in any of the subfolders of the java project.

Comment: If you want to move the database to other system, [look here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/copying-databases.html).

Comment: mysql cannot be embedded in your application. there are other solutions such as Derby etc

Comment: @GurwinderSingh thanks. I thought about creating the dump .sql file but if the client don't want to install mysql and start xampp server everytime, I'll need to allow the application to work without xampp or mysql or mysql workbench.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh does this mean I need to rewrite all the stored procedures and redefine the table properties from scratch?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131432/discussion-between-gurwinder-singh-and-p3ace).